# Setting up a home 'vocal booth'

Tags: microphone

I'm looking at recording some vocals and looking for tips on how to get good results on a budget.

My set-up is based around a Zoom H4 on a tripod with a pop filter. As this is hooked up to the PC I can't move it very far.

The room is 3x5m. As it's a home office/study used by the whole family there is not much scope for sound treatments on the room as a whole, but I've see talk of using cushions etc around the mic to reduce the effect of the room. I'd consider something like that as long is it can be easily set up when it is needed.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just recorded some vocals in a similar sized room this past weekend. One trick I found online was to take extra boom mic stands and some sheets or blankets. Use those to create "walls" around the vocalist, especially behind them (where the mic will be pointing). Make sure the blanket wall is taller than the vocalist.

I've also found it helpful to simply have lots of stuff elsewhere in the room - pillows, cushions, shoe boxes, etc. (Assuming they don't rattle or make some other noise :). That's especially true in the corners and along the wall.

Answer (score 1):

DIY: Portable Mini Vocal Booth -
http://www.instructables.com/id/Portable-Mini-Vocal-Booth/